# Generate a file from a loop

Tags: bash

How would one write a script that would create a file that is called `post-data.txt` that would contain 3000 records of json data as follows:

```
{"firstName":"random_string_of10_characters","lastName":"random_string_of10_characters","email":"test+1@domain.com"}
{"firstName":"random_string_of10_characters","lastName":"random_string_of10_characters","email":"test+2@domain.com"}
{"firstName":"random_string_of10_characters","lastName":"random_string_of10_characters","email":"test+3@domain.com"}
...
{"firstName":"random_string_of10_characters","lastName":"random_string_of10_characters","email":"test+3000@domain.com"}
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash
file_location=/home/test/$1.json
if [ -e $policy ]; then
  echo "File $1.json already exists!"
else
  cat > $file_location <<EOF
{"firstName":"x","lastName":"y","email":"test@domain.com"}
EOF
fi
```

I hardcoded the text but I don't know how to generate random strings and increment an email address :( Thank you.

Comment: So really you're asking two questions: 1) How can I generate random strings? 2) How can I increment a variable? Please limit your post to one question. Although, have you done any research? It should be easy to find the answers.

Comment: BTW your script could use some cleaning up. Check out [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) for basic advice.

Comment: @TimJohnson : What is the `cat` command supposed to do? It expects something from standard input and copies it to your json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=post_data.json

name() {
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1
}

exec > "$file"
echo "{"

for i in {1..3000}; do
    echo "{\"firstName\": \"$(name)\", \"lastName\": \"$(name)\", \"email\": \"test+${i}@domain.com\"},"
done

echo "}"
```

Here is the file content:

```
{
{"firstName": "R0b24KRMCX", "lastName": "H4RpNLUMM0", "email": "test+1@domain.com"},
{"firstName": "WcThrrFUht", "lastName": "zEgMb2mMva", "email": "test+2@domain.com"},
{"firstName": "3NBRZPOeT0", "lastName": "fvuNtmhh7x", "email": "test+3@domain.com"},
...
{"firstName": "I8QD9sr8ke", "lastName": "Inbb4cUKqQ", "email": "test+3000@domain.com"},
}
```

Comment: Every time you write `>> $file`, that re-opens the file at the start of the command, and closes it when done. That means your loop is re-opening the file (and closing it) 3000 times! Just open it once; `exec >"$file"` at the top of the script will redirect *all* stdout there.

Comment: Also, note that questions that don't have a *narrow, specific* focus are generally best not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). How to generate random strings is *one* question, and it's one that's already in our knowledgebase. How to increment a counter? Likewise, *one* question, and a duplicate at that. Thus, this question is eligible for close (outside the "as defined in the help center" criteria linked from the bottom bullet in How to Answer) on multiple counts.

Comment: Wait, not narrow focus? I literally specified a precise example of the problem with sample data and what I could do on my own with my limited skills. Suggesting to ask multiple questions makes no sense as may be an individual with limited skills would want to have an overall solution to a perceived simple question without piece mealing from numerous posts. I do not understand your logic. May be help instead?

Comment: @TimJohnson See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267438/generate-a-file-from-a-loop#comment99150721_56267438) on your post. Also see [ask]. To be fair, it's not a terrible question, just not focused enough.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the insight. I will try to be more focused possibly referencing other links I found

Comment: Hi. I'm getting "tr: Illegal byte sequence" when running on a mac. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: @TimJohnson Try to  export `LC_CTYPE=C` env variable ([link](https://github.com/mrowa44/emojify/pull/12/files)).